# Use fontgen.py make custom font for Pebble

Tags: python, pebble-sdk

I use fontgen.py (from Pebble SDK) to make custom font for Pebble, but it fire error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fontgen.py", line 4, in <module>
    import freetype
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\freetype_py-1.0.2-py3.5.egg\freetype\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\freetype_py-1.0.2-py3.5.egg\freetype\raw.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 360, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'FT_Select_Size' not found
```

I can't solve this problem. Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using fontgen.py to convert your own fonts? You can just insert a TTF file into resources, setup the proper media declaration for it in your app's info JSON, and use it right from within your code. No manual generation needed.

Comment: I made language pack for my own, not app. I don't know how, search everywhere and nothing.